# I discovered the answer to my own unanswered bounty question

Tags: discussion, bounties, etiquette

Should I answer it only after the bounty is lost?(especially since I think I may not have given enough info)

Comment: I recently had a somewhat similar situation and made my post Community Wiki.

Comment: Since the bounty has already ended (and is in its grace period), it seems unlikely that anyone is going to answer it.  Answering it yourself will not affect the bounty; it will just go unrewarded.

Answer (score 4):

If I were you I would wait (at least) until the grace period to post a self answer. The reason:

1. You already made an investment. Maybe someone will come up with an extra advice.
2. Moreover, it is good thing to be a "benefactor".

So, if your question is too specific to hold option number 1, go with the number 2. If none is possible, then, post an answer after the bounty is gone.